# Delete two parents in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following:

..

```
<ContentsNodes>
    <Node id="14003"/>
    <Node id="13944"/>
    <Node id="292"/>
    <Node id="8418">
        <ChildNodes>
            <Node id="8420"/>
            <Node id="8421"/>
            <Node id="47316">
                <ChildNodes>
                    <Node id="8423"/>
                    <Node id="8424"/>
                    <Node id="8425"/>
                    <Node id="8426"/>
                    <Node id="8427"/>
                    <Node id="15682"/>
                </ChildNodes>
            </Node>
            <Node id="55240">
                <ChildNodes>
                    <Node id="8429"/>
                    <Node id="8430"/>
                </ChildNodes>
            </Node>
            <Node id="8431"/>
            <Node id="55241">
                <ChildNodes>
                    <Node id="8433"/>
                    <Node id="8434"/>
                    <Node id="8435"/>
                    <Node id="8436"/>
                    <Node id="8439"/>
                    <Node id="8440"/>
                    <Node id="8441"/>
                    <Node id="8438"/>
                </ChildNodes>
            </Node>
            <Node id="12977"/>
            <Node id="2340"/>
        </ChildNodes>
    </Node>
</ContentsNodes>
```

..

I would like to:

- get rid of `<Node id="47316">`
- get rid of `<Node id="55240">`
- get the children of both nodes at the same level as `<Node id="8421"/>`.

In other words:

```
<ContentsNodes>
<Node id="14003"/>
<Node id="13944"/>
<Node id="292"/>
<Node id="8418">
    <ChildNodes>
        <Node id="8420"/>
        <Node id="8421"/>
        <Node id="8423"/>
        <Node id="8424"/>
        <Node id="8425"/>
        <Node id="8426"/>
        <Node id="8427"/>
        <Node id="15682"/>
        <Node id="8429"/>
        <Node id="8430"/>
        <Node id="8431"/>
        <Node id="55241">
            <ChildNodes>
                <Node id="8433"/>
                <Node id="8434"/>
                <Node id="8435"/>
                <Node id="8436"/>
                <Node id="8439"/>
                <Node id="8440"/>
                <Node id="8441"/>
                <Node id="8438"/>
            </ChildNodes>
        </Node>
        <Node id="12977"/>
        <Node id="2340"/>
    </ChildNodes>
</Node>
</ContentsNodes>
```

I am able to delete the superfluous nodes with:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//path/to/Node[3]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//path/to/Node[4]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

But I end up with:

```
<ContentsNodes>
<Node id="14003"></Node>
<Node id="13944"></Node>
<Node id="292"></Node>
<Node id="8418">
    <ChildNodes>
        <Node id="8420"></Node>
        <Node id="8421"></Node>

            <ChildNodes>
                <Node id="8423"></Node>
                <Node id="8424"></Node>
                <Node id="8425"></Node>
                <Node id="8426"></Node>
                <Node id="8427"></Node>
                <Node id="15682"></Node>
            </ChildNodes>

            <ChildNodes>
                <Node id="8429"></Node>
                <Node id="8430"></Node>
            </ChildNodes>

        <Node id="8431"></Node>
        <Node id="55241">
              <ChildNodes>
                <Node id="8433"></Node>
                <Node id="8434"></Node>
                <Node id="8435"></Node>
                <Node id="8436"></Node>
                <Node id="8439"></Node>
                <Node id="8440"></Node>
                <Node id="8441"></Node>
                <Node id="8438"></Node>
            </ChildNodes>
        </Node>
        <Node id="12977"></Node>
        <Node id="2340"></Node>
    </ChildNodes>
</Node>
</ContentsNodes>
```

So I still need to delete the `<ChildNodes>` under `<Node id="8421"></Node>`. How do I do that with one transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to simply replace your current `xsl:apply-templates` with a more targetted one that selects the grandchild nodes

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*/Node"/>
```

For example, try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Node[@id = '47316' or @id = '55240']">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/Node"/>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, add a template that also ignore the `ChildNode` elements of the nodes you wish to ignore

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Node[@id = '47316' or @id = '55240']">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="Node[@id = '47316' or @id = '55240']/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the first XSLT you suggested and worked like a charm.